# C# generic method for returning maxId

Tags: c#, generic-list

I would like to have a method that could perform this code on other objects I have (For example: prize, person, team and so on.), so I don't have to write the same code multiple times and just put let's say GetMaxId(List< Person > persons, Person person). 
Each of my objects has an Id property.
I'm using this so when i save to text file through user input in my winform application, so i can generate the id that be 1 bigger based on the current number of eg Persons in the text file.

```
public static int GetMaxId(List<Prize> prizes, Prize prize)
    {
        int maxId = 1;
        if (prizes.Count > 0)
            maxId = prizes.Max(p => p.Id) + 1;

        prize.Id = maxId;
        return prize.Id;
    }
```

So, what i would like is in each of the classes, for example i want to return the id for the person when creating a new person but i don't want to modify the code from taking in parameters for Prize and having to change it to Person.
i would like a method that takes generic parameters so when i call it in Person class, i can just pass the (list persons, Person person).

I don't know which type to pass in the original method so that i can reuse it in other classes.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? You must give us more details. Do you want the function taking as parameters different object? Do you want all classes to have such a method? 
Take a look at inheritance and interfaces. It is impossible to give an answer with so few pieces of information.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi sry for not clarifying enough. Hope this explains it.

Comment: Sorry but it did not in my opinion. And you still have not told us which programming language you are using.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi i thought it would be visible in the title C#.

Comment: You are right about it but you should put also in tags as you did now because generally questions are categorized with the tag.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi will do. Ok one last try: i want my method too be like GetMaxId(list<something> something, Something something), so that i can just pass different things into it and do the same thing..without having to change it in multiple places where it says prize or prizes. in this example

Comment: Define an interface with an `Id` property. Have all the classes implement that interface and write the method taking in an `IEnumerable` of that interface....

Comment: For the question it is better you create some working example code with classes (repeating the function in each class id needed) so that other people can understand what you would like to do and can help in avoiding repeating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think what you want is a generic function to retrieve the next id of a collection. You can try using generics.

Something like this:

```
public static int GetNextId<T>(List<T> items, Func<T,int> selector)
    {
        if (items.Count < 1)
            return 1;

        return items.Max(selector)+1;
    }
```

And you use the function like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() {PersonID=1 },
            new Person() {PersonID=2 },

        };

        var nextId = GetNextId(persons, i => i.PersonID);//returns 3
    }
```

Comment: Tnx, this solved my problem. I didn't know i could use Func for this. Very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using an interface, where all your things would implement this `IHaveId` interface to ensure they have this id property.  The `getMaxId` function is generic and requires only that your list be a list of things with id properties which implement the `IHaveId` interface.

You can see this working at https://dotnetfiddle.net/pnX7Ph.

```
public interface IHaveId {
    int id { get; }
}

public class Thing1 : IHaveId {
    private int _id;
    public Thing1(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
    int IHaveId.id {
        get { return this._id; }
    }
}

public class Thing2 : IHaveId {
    private int _id;
    public Thing2(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
    int IHaveId.id {
        get { return this._id; }
    }
}   


public static int getMaxId<T>(List<T> list) where T : IHaveId {
    return list.Max(i => i.id);
}


public static void Main()
{
    List<IHaveId> things = new List<IHaveId>();
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        things.Add(new Thing1(i));
    }
    for (var i=10; i<15; i++) {
        things.Add(new Thing2(i));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Max id is " + getMaxId(things));
}
```